# RecyclerView Children count smaller than the number of children

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I have a very strange problem today: I have a RecyclerView that shows some thumbnails horizontally, I use an `smoothScrollToPosition` to navigate to the item I need, but I noticed a problem: it will not scroll to the last item. Upon further debugging, I found that my recyclerview has less children than it displays! I see five items, with 3 displayed at a time. but the children count (gotten with `recyclerView.getChildCount`) returns 4 instead of five, and I can't get the last child with `getChildAt(4)`. Even more strange, the `adapter.getItemCount()` returns 5, and `recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()` returns 5...

Upon inspecting the `layoutAdapter`, `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount()` returns 5, and `recyclerView..getLayoutManager().getChildCount() returns 4...

**I need two things**: First, I need my recyclerView to scroll to that last item, and Second: I need to be able to get all children, since I do some modifications on them as the user interact with the items.

Some code:

```
// Scrolling and editing the item inside the recyclerView
// It doesn't scroll to position 4, even having a item there...
mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, position);

// the code bellow returns null if position = 4, even if the recyclerView adapter has a item at index 4, and it is visible...
ImageView iv = (ImageView) recyclerView.getChildAt(position);
if (iv != null) {
    iv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    iv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    ImageView ivo = (ImageView) recyclerView.getChildAt(position - 1);
    if (position - 1 == 0) {
        ivo.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        ivo.setPadding(0, 10, 10, 10);
    }
    ivo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
}
```

smoothScrollToPosition implementation:

```
public class SnappingLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 150f;

    public SnappingLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
                                       int position) {
        RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new TopSnappedSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()){
            @Override
            public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                return new PointF(0, 1);
            }

            //This returns the milliseconds it takes to scroll one pixel.
            @Override
            protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
            }
        };
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }

    private class TopSnappedSmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {
        public TopSnappedSmoothScroller(Context context) {
            super(context);

        }

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return SnappingLinearLayoutManager.this
                    .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return SNAP_TO_ANY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RecycleView does not hold all of the items from the adapter. It only have views of displayed views + some extra at the begining and end of the recycler view list ,so it could render it faster. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To scroll to a position in the list you can use [`scrollToPosition(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)). The position you pass in would be the index of the last item like this:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount())
```

I was able to get this approach working with the v7 RecyclerView and android's LinearLayoutManager.

build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    ...
}
```

RecyclerView layout code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/item_list"
  android:name="fbalashov.spikeapp.ItemListFragment"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Then when I want to scroll to the top of the list I just call my scrollToBottom method:

```
private void scrollToBottom() {
  recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
}
```

This causes the RecyclerView to smoothly scroll to the last item in the list.

2) As Rafal stated, the RecyclerView (and the ListView) only draw the items that are visible on the screen + a item or two buffer on the top and bottom to make scrolling look nice. As you scroll, it will "recycle" the views and populate them with the data from your adapter. So the view that is scrolled off the top will be re-used on the bottom of the list with data form the next item.

Thus, you cannot get ALL the views for the items in the adapter at the same time. However you can get all the items in the adapter, modify them and then trigger the adapter to redraw the views in the recyclerView using [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). Example:

```
// getItems() is a method you will have to add to you adapter to get the items from your 
// adapter. Otherwise you can add a method in your adapter to update the items.
List<DataType> items = adapter.getItems();
for (DataType item : items) {
  // make some change to each item
}
// this will force the recycler view to redraw its views
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can also make more targeted changes to items in the adapter by just updating those items in the adapter and using [notifyItemChanged(position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)).

Comment: Thanks Dr. Nitpick! I didn't use `scrollToPosition` because it isn't animated, and other posts suggested that I should use `smoothScrollToPosition` for animated scrolls... Can you please point update or point me to a location where I can learn how get a animated scroll with `scrollToPosition`? About the count, thanks for the advice, I will try to tag the views in some way so I can edit them as needed...

Comment: Are you using [RecyclerView from support v7](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview)? I was able to use it with android's LinearLayoutManager to implement smooth scrolling to the bottom of the list without having to override `smoothScrollToPosition`. Ill add example code to my answer.